# router outlet with routes from child component

Tags: angular, routes

I have a parent component with a  inside.
Also, I have a child component (sidebar) that has buttons with [routerLink] like this:

```js
<button 
   [routerLink]="['/learning/account-settings/account']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" 
   type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      <p>
         <i-feather name="user" data-feather="user" class="sidebar-icons"></i-feather>
         Account
      </p>
</button>
```

What I would like to happen is to have a static menu on the left and on the right to have routed components using router-outlet.

But the actual behaviour is when I click on a button, it does not give me the component on the left side where router outlet is, it uses the router-outlet of app.component.

How can I solve this?
Is it because the [routerLink] is in the child component and router-outlet doesn't know about that?

Comment: you can use named router-outlet: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#template-variable-references